# Properties of cumulative distribution function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

$F(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
x^2 & 0 \le x < \frac{1}{2} \\
\alpha & x = \frac{1}{2} \\
1 - 2^{-2x} & x > \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$

1. Find $\text{Pr}\left (\frac{1}{4} < X \le \frac{3}{4}\right)$.
2. Find $\alpha$.

Please help, i am a bit confused because of the jump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $P\left(\tfrac14<X\leq \tfrac34\right)=P\left(X\leq \tfrac34\right)-P\left(X\leq \tfrac14\right)$.
2. A cumulative distribution function is right-continuous. That is $F(x)=\lim_{y\downarrow x}F(y)$. This enables you to determine $\alpha=F(\tfrac12)$.